# I have a question about the 'resources' folder for applying css to the spring mvc project in intellij

Tags: css, jsp, intellij-idea

I want to apply Bootstrap's css file when creating spring mvc project in intellij, but I have a question.

In the Project Structure, the path is set to src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml, and the resources file was created and css files were inserted, as in eclipse, but the css file was inserted under webapp/resources.

However, if you don't put the same css file under the WEB-INF/views/resources, the line will be drawn with a highlighter as shown in the **picture**, but I wonder if this is an error or not.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3tin.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can point the cursor at the warning and press Alt+Enter to see the detailed information.